# How to properly resize large images in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, image-manipulation, gd

For a website I run, users can upload pictures they've drawn to a gallery.  We create a thumbnail and a small view of that image to display to other users (clicking the small view image shows the full sized image).

With this in mind, I created a very simple resize script.  In most cases this script works perfectly.  However, I've come across a single odd case in which the script messes up entirely.

When running the file http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/2268/935full.png (1641x3121) through the script (which creates one thumbnail with a max width or height of 150 and another of 400) we get a perfect thumbnail http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/5803/935thumb.png (78x150) and a small view image sized properly, but which is cut off and stretched http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/4002/935show.png (211 x 400).

With that in mind, my question is: Is this a problem in PHP or a logic error?  And how can I fix it?

Thank you for your time.  The code I use to create these thumbnails is below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Creates a thumbnail for any type of pre-existing image. Always saves as PNG image
 *
 * @param string - The location of the pre-existing image.
 * @param string - The location to save the thumbnail, including filename and extension.
 * @param int    - The Maximum Width, Default of 150
 * @param int    - The Maximum Height, Default of 150
 * @return bool  - Success of saving the thumbnail.
 */
function imagecreatethumbnail($file,$output,$max_width = 150,$max_height = 150)
{
        $img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file));
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($file);
        if($height > $max_height || $width > $max_width)
        {
                if($width > $height)
                {
                        $thumb_width = $max_width;
                        $thumb_height = ceil(($height * $thumb_width)/$width);
                }
                else
                {
                        $thumb_height = $max_height;
                        $thumb_width = ceil(($width * $thumb_height)/$height);
                }
        } else {
                $thumb_width = $width;
                $thumb_height = $height;
        }
        imagesavealpha($img,true);
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height);
        imagesavealpha($thumb,true);
        imagealphablending($thumb,false);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb,$img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);
        $return = imagepng($thumb,$output);
        imagedestroy($img);
        imagedestroy($thumb);
        return $return;
}
```

Comment: Does the script interrupt (due to max_execution_time, or memory_limit)?

Comment: Running your code with `imagecreatethumbnail("http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/2268/935full.png", "m.png", 400, 400);` produces the correct image. PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny8. Php's GD is version 5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny8.

Comment: It must be some weird PHP GD error then.

Running PHP 5.2.14, which says GD Version is "bundled (2.0.34 compatible)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the ceil() functions? The image functions will automatically convert floats to integers anyway.

**EDIT:**

See if this works:

```
if($width > $max_width && $height * $thumb_width / $width < $max_width)
{
    $thumb_width = $max_width;
    $thumb_height = $height * $thumb_width / $width;
}
elseif($height > $max_height && $width * $thumb_height / $height < $max_height)
{
    $thumb_height = $max_height;
    $thumb_width = $width * $thumb_height / $height;
}
else
{
    $thumb_width = $width;
    $thumb_height = $height;
}
```

Comment: Well, I can't make images that are x.xxx pixels.

Comment: In fact, the issue isn't the numbers being returned.  Doing the math out by hand its still calculating the proper size for the image.  Just not resizing the image properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library and tell me if the same occurs:

http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/